# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined when using Google Sheets onEdit functionality

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Attempting to run the code below as a Script in Google Sheets. The goal is to be able to use the
**onEdit Trigger**

Unfortunately, the code below is giving a:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit  @ Code.gs:4
```

Error

```
function onEdit( e )
 {
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FXKLog")
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var range = e.getRange();

 }
```

What is the problem?

Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: From `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, in your script, when you directly run your script, I think that such an error occurs because of no event object `e`. If you want to achieve `The goal is to be able to use the onEdit Trigger`, please edit a cell. By this, your script is run by the OnEdit trigger.

Comment: I know my question has been closed but this helped too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KC7pBjD3GGw